# How to ignore extra arguments passed to `git-alias`es?

Tags: shell

Googling different approaches how to ignore extra arguments passed to `git-alias`es

```
git hi v1 v2 v3
```

I have found:

1. `hi = "!echo $1 #"`   (why `"` are required?)
2. `hi = "!sh -c 'echo $1' -"`
3. `hi = "!sh -c 'echo $1' --"`  (what is difference in compare to `-`?)
4. `hi = "!f(){ echo $1; };f"`

What is the benefit and gotchas of each?

Comment: I see someone voted-to-close as "too broad", but it's worth thinking about this in terms of what `git` passes to the shell, when it invokes a shell (when `!` is present). Git expands `$<number>` in place, then passes all arguments in the `argv` array it sends, via `execve` or equivalent, to `sh` (which may be POSIX `sh` or some version of bash). The rest is all really questions about how the shell / bash treats its argv array.

Comment: @torek: I have found `GIT_TRACE=2` env variable to see how args are passed. And all cases seems similar. Just want to find recommendations which solution is better.

Comment: Right—but that's still a question for *shell* programming: when would you prefer for your command-line argv array to contain, e.g., "echo v1 # v1 v2 v3", when would you prefer "sh -c 'echo v1' - v1 v2 v3", and so on (except with more precision about what's in each array element). In other words, this isn't a *git* question, this is a *shell* question.

Comment: @torek: Tags are fixed. So there only one question about git: Why aliases sometimes works without quotes?

Comment: The double quotes in the `.gitconfig` line are required to pass the `#` through to the shell (otherwise Git eats the `#`-to-end-of-line as a comment). Once passed through to the shell, the shell treats `#` as a comment. The details get sticky on Windows, I think, but I don't use Windows.